# Stripe Webhook Custom Header

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I am working on a project where we create Payment link using Stripe and share the link to the customer.

Once the customer made the payment we use Stripe webhook to check the payment status. and we are sending some metadata using the generate payment link.

What I need ?
Imaging that i created a order # 12345 and the payment is done. I want stripe webhook to send me that Order number in request header. I don't want to retrieve the details in payload.

is it possible in stripe webhook ?

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to customize the Strip event header. You should set your custom data to the object's [metadata](https://docs.stripe.com/api/metadata), and retrieve it from the event payload.